# Elliptical Curve Cryptography decryption resulting point at infinity?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am building a web app to encrypt and decrypt using an ECC algorithm.

I use the following curve parameters:

```
Prime p = 43
a = 7
b = 3

public key e1 = 11
private key d = 3
let say i want to encrypt character that is on point (38, 12)
```

So I calculate its cipher which results in

```
c1 = (11, 32)
c2 = (27, 40)
```

I'm sure that both of my cipher is correct because I already calculated it manually.

The problem is, when I want to decrypt it, I have to calculate

```
M = c2 - d * c1
d * c1 = (27, 3)
```

so,

```
M = (27, 40) - (27, 3)
```

Since point `(27, 40)` and `(27, 3)` is a straight line, it will resulting point infinity. Beacuse we can’t calculate the lambda since

```
x2-x1 = 21 - 27 = 0
```

and the lambda formula is

```
y2-y2 / x2-x1
```

and we can’t divide number to zero.

How to solve this problem? How do I get my original point if my cipher resulting point at infinity?

Comment: 'Since point (27, 40) and (27, 3) is a straight line, it will resulting point infinity.'; actually, not.  $(27, 40) - (27, 3) = (27,40) + (27,40)$, that is, we have a point doubling...

Comment: how can (27, 3) can turn to (27, 40) and not (27, -3)? please explain, i  dont understand, hehe

Comment: @hphp: $(27,40)$ and $(27,-3)$ represent the same point.  Computations are done in $\mathbb{F}_{43}$: $-3 \bmod 43 = 40$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the answer from the comments, starting with [poncho](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55919/elliptical-curve-cryptography-decryption-resulting-point-at-infinity#comment123782_55919):

> Since point $(27, 40)$ and $(27, 3)$ is a straight line, it will resulting
>   point infinity.'; actually, not. $(27,40)−(27,3)=(27,40)+(27,40)$, that
>   is, we have a point doubling...

which resulted in

> how can $(27, 3)$ can turn to $(27, 40)$ and not $(27, -3)$?

which is resolved by [user94293](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55919/elliptical-curve-cryptography-decryption-resulting-point-at-infinity#comment123785_55919)

> $(27,40)$ and $(27,−3)$ represent the same point. Computations are done in
>   $\mathbb F_{43}: −3\bmod43=40$